# Triple-boot Ubuntu with existing dual boot Window 7 and 10

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot

I would like to install Ubuntu alongside my existing dual boot Windows 7 and Windows 10.

During installation of the Ubuntu "trial" it recognized Windows 10 but no mention of Windows 7. This concerned me.

I had Windows 7 originally and installed Windows 10 after. I seem to have two different boot menus, which alternate depending on which OS was last booted. Or, to be more precise, the appearance of the boot menu is different depending which OS last booted.

What is the safest way to install Ubuntu alongside my two existing OSes and keeping Windows 7 as the default OS?

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide.

Comment: I dropped dual boot 25 years ago. Triple boot is likely destined to problems. Truly it is time to rethink your strategy. I am running Windows 10, 7, Kali and Ubuntu all simultaneously and all working well Nothing I do with one system impedes any other system. Just a thought.

Comment: @John How are you running them simultaneously without dual/triple boot?

Comment: I use Virtual Machines .  That is a much better way than triple boot.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 usually installed using MBR. Windows 10 generally uses UEFI so the first thing you need to determine is whether you are using an MBR or UEFI boot method for your windows install. Whichever you are using for windows you must also use with Mint. Problems you will encounter if you mix them are explained at the site below.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Don't use the Install Alongside option. Use the manual install method which in Mint will be called Something else.
There isn't really any point in creating a partition from windows because it can't create a Linux filesystem. You will need to format for Linux anyway so just shrink your windows partition(s) to create unallocated space for Mint. The link below explains how to install Ubuntu 14.04 and its installer is the same as the Mint installer so if you are using MBR following the instructions should work. It doesn't explain UEFI so if you have UEFI it won't help.

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/u...all-guide.html

Comment: Is it possible i have both UEFI and MBR boot menus? After previously loading Win 7 the next boot menu is a black screen with the two OSes in white font. After previously loading Windows 10 the boot screen is a blue (colourful blue, not BIOS blue) Windows 10 screen. These 2 screens alternate as i selected a different OS the previous time, if this makes sense?

Comment: Some UEFI builds are compatible with MBR emulations, with this I mean you can use the MBR menu inside UEFI build. The reason why the boot menu changes after loading an OS is because Windows 7 doesn't have a proper built-in boot menu while Windows 10 does. I guess the colorful blue boot screen you are talking about looks similar to the Windows 10 default theme. Windows 10 has its own boot menu, that's why it shows that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but aren't we confusing UEFI Bios and MBR here.
MBR or GPT is the way the Hard Disk creates it's file system  which isn't directly related to the type of Bios you are running UEFI or Legacy (Award or Pheonix) bios
When you buy a new Hard Drive It will ask you to initialize ( at least on Windows it will) and you have the Choice of MBR or GPT and an explanation that if your drive is larger than 2Tb you should think about selecting GPT ( but you don't have to)and you don't if you want to read the drive with older systems.
UEFI bios will address both MBR and GPT disks. The Issue is the OS. The OS Win10 (and Win8.1) will not run on anything other than UEFI for the same reason Mac OS will not run on a PC.( It can but you have to hack it)
In both cases the OS checks the inventory held in bios ( installed components) and checks the compatability ( whether or Not Microsoft or Apple allow the hardware) before allowing an install or letting the bios hand over to the OS.
This is the Con here when you are told your hardware isn't supported ( go buy new hardware that you don't need)
In the case of Win10 (and win8.1) it adds security to the bios which in effect stops you altering the bios without Win10 giving permission to do so. In otherwords if you get locked out of Windows and cant get to the reset/restore windows menu and you want to legacy boot linux from a CD to try to fix it you can't.
I have in my possession a perfectly funtioning Lenovo laptop that came preinstalled with Win8.1( given to me because it didn't work)
The HDD had failed I tried to fit a new drive and load Win7 (it wouldn't have it)mainly as you can't get into the bios to change settings to get it to see a CD drive or a USB without windows allowing it so it keeps trying to boot from the HDD that isn't there.
In the end I managed to clone the original drive to the new drive and it fired right up.
You can then ask windows to let you edit the bios at which point you're told you don't have permission.In otherwords you are stuck with Windows8.1 or upgrading to a later version as long a Windows allows it. you can't put Win7 or linux on the machine even if you wanted to, and reflashing the Bios doesn't work either because although the bios is upgraded you still can't access it to change it without windows allowing it and as the hardware owner you don't have permission.Good isn't it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).